# Python dictonary to set for operations

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two filesystems from the same system but at different times, dumped and converted to dictionaries with

```
"FileName":MD5_Hash
```

I further convert them into sets and use

```
SetA = set(dictA.items())
SetB.difference(SetA)
```

to find new and changed files. Is this the right way to go about this? Is the operation comparing the MD5 values of files with same name?

How do I go about verifying the output if this is the correct way? (I plan to make a small filesystem with around 100 files and manually change a few and test the program).

Thanks!

Comment: the hash of a dictionary is only the keys so your not comparing the hashes at all

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have been using set(dictX.items()) for creation of the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert a `dict` to a `set`, you'll only get the keys:

```
>>> x
{'2': 4, '5': 2}
>>> set(x)
set(['2', '5'])
```

Because you want the keys, too, you can do:

```
>>> as_set = set(x.iteritems())
>>> as_set
set([('5', 2), ('2', 4)])
>>> dict(as_set)
{'2': 4, '5': 2}
```

Set difference functions will work for this.

Comment: Hey i have been using `set(x.items())` which should be giving the same output as your answer.